# s3.copyObject not copying object, just headers

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am currently using [aws2js](https://github.com/SaltwaterC/aws2js) to interface with Amazon S3 and I am using the copyObject function, however the copyObject function isn't copying the object just the headers.  ex:

The original object:

```
 { headers: 
     { 'x-amz-id-2': 'yTZGt+Jp/wwv+UbQCcfzh7Wsq123H21516GNu123bc4y123Yi/aSXiP2123zSgji0EO',
       'x-amz-request-id': '2786D8473EB153D6',
        date: 'Sat, 28 Dec 2013 06:52:48 GMT',
        'last-modified': 'Sat, 28 Dec 2013 06:34:06 GMT',
        'x-amz-version-id': 'dWxmMRG6szNgL5BfZBtw3uOBW123UpXi',
        etag: '"52a5f45632d3aa14e747254320123219"',
        'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
        'content-type': 'application/pdf',
        'content-length': '68008',
        server: 'AmazonS3' },
        buffer: <Buffer 25 50 ...> }
```

The "copied" object:

```
 { 'x-amz-id-2': '7sDoDwJbuUydx/57Vp/a0PDMEkSO3c57h37xshLF+OcMYBg34MDPmNcnO0LMVLsC',  
   'x-amz-request-id': 'FFBFAB7586CEF2DE',
   date: 'Sat, 28 Dec 2013 06:52:48 GMT',
   'x-amz-version-id': 'WlFR96umHE6yiYD_ec_4_kPtlUhI_sfs',
   etag: '"d41d8cg98f06b204e9500998ecf8427e"',
   'content-length': '0',  
   server: 'AmazonS3' }
```

Why is it "copying" and creating a 0 Byte object?

```
var acl = 'private';
var headers = ['x-amz-meta-unique', 'content-type', 'content-encoding'];
aws2js.copyObject('bucket1/filename.pdf', 'bucket2/filename.pdf', acl, headers, function(error, result) {
    console.log('result: ', error, result);
});
```

Comment: What is being logged for 'result: ', error, result  ?